# Как правильно преобразовать object в array

Tags: ajax, json

Задаю вопрос еще тут.

```
$.ajax('api.php', {
    method: 'post',
    data: j,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {console.log(result.length)}
}
```

если скрипт возвращает массив `[{"country":"ua","city":"ki"},{"country":"ua","city":"ki"},{"country":"ua","city":"rv"}]` (изначальный массив начиная с индекса 0, то результат - массив.

Если возврат `{"11":{"country":"de","city":"mh"},"12":{"country":"de","city":"bn"}}` то результат - обьект, с свойствами "11,12.." доступ к ним по `result[11]` есть, но как его соединить с другим массивом? `.concat(result)` не подходит. `resarr= Array.from(result);` не дает результата. Т.е. если скрипт возвращает массив начиная не с "0"го индекса, то $.ajax воспринимает его как объект.

```
keysarr= Object.keys(result);
tmpvar=firstarr.length+keysarr.length; //сразу в скобках for не считает, ну и ладно)
for (x=firstarr.length; x<tmpvar;x++) {
    resarr[x]=result[x]
}
tem=first.concat(resarr);
```

получается массив : `[0="",1="",11=["country"="de","city"="mh"],12=["country"="de","city"="bn"]]`

Если добавить в цикле

```
for(x=0;x<resarr.length;x++){resarr.shift();} //убрать первые ключи без индекса
```

то получается массив сортированный по символам unicode

```
[0,1,2,25,26,27,28,29,3,30,31]
```

как это можно поправить?

Comment: Приведи конкретные объекты и массивы, которые ты имеешь в js.  И результат, который хочешь получить

Comment: [0=[country='ukraine',city='kyiv'],1=[country='ukraine',city='kharkov'],...,11=[country='germany',city='munich'],12=[country='germany',city='berlin'],...,2=[country='ukraine',city='vinnitsa'],..

Comment: это *не* json. и *не* объекты из яваскрипт, больше похоже на дамп переменой из php. Я говорил, про конкретные значения которые ты имеешь **уже на клиенте**. А так же необходим результат, который ты ожидаешь. Отредактировать вопрос ты можешь с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: на клиенте имею после слияния двух массивов res[0,1,10,11....2,21,22...], надо получить res[0,1,2,3...,9,10,11,12...19,20]

Comment: в яваскрипте это невозможно, так как нарушает синтаксис.

Comment: дело не в синтаксисе, написал "на скорую руку". Дело в сортировке. Да яваскрипт так сортирует, и проблемка в том, что из первого массива уже показаны данные, а надо добавить данные из второго и потом к ним обращаться по индексу. На данный момент собираю два массива, пересортировываю и вывожу все данные заново. При количестве строк +- 70-100 еще норм, но выводить заново 800 строк при чем форматированных - яваскрипт начинает долго думать

Comment: Еще раз: добавь **в вопрос**. Пример входных и выходных данных. Сейчас непонятно какие объекты/массивы у тебя есть, и что ты хочешь получить на выходе. Отредактировать вопрос ты можешь с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: Что должно в итоге получиться? массив или объект? со значениями или с индексами?

Comment: в результате массив с индексами 0,1,2...9,10 но впорос как это сделать не упорядочивая его вручную. Я так понял никак. Поетому беру предыдущий массив и в него в цикле добавляю данные из другого

Comment: А начальный массив индексов откуда берется?

Comment: На сколько я понял проблема в том, что сначала может прийти [0,1,2], потом [22,23], сначала все ок [0,1,2,22,23], а потом приходит [3,4] и должно стать [0,1,2,3,4,22,23], а сейчас получается [0,1,2,22,23,3,4] - Так?

Comment: Сначала приходит [0,1,2,3], потом [21,22,23] и становится  после concat [0,1,2,21,22,23,3] и т.д. с [30,31,32] а хочется [0,1,2,3,4...21,22,23...30,31] что как бы "противоречит" сортировке яваскрипта. И в режиме [0,1,11,2,21] яваскрипт перестает воспринимать эту переменную как массив и функция "sort" не работает. Только в цикле в новый массив. Поскольку массив многомерный, с размером 6,8-9,4Мб во-первых большая задерка при этих операциях во-вторых браузер сьедает много памяти на страницу. Изначально массив формируется в php и возвращается кусками после array_slice с сохранением названий ключей

Comment: можешь добавить в вопрос [сниппет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999)?  чтобы воспроизвелось поведение? у меня не получилось перемешивание